# Error in HTML scrollspy / Javascript class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a website with a scroll spy, and so far it has worked. The problem is, I am aiming to add a class when an `<a>` is clicked.
It has not worked, and I cannot understand why.

Please excuse me if this is a simple mistake.

(Read the code below if you do not understand)
Make sure to open it in full page.

Thank you for your help, and ask if you need more explanation.

```html
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.active{

  background-color: red;
}




</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" style="width: 250px;">
    
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closeBTN" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" style="display: none;">✕</a>
  <div class="active">
  <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#Home">About</a>
  </div>
    <div class="">
  <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#AboutUs">Services</a>
    </div>
      <div class="">
  <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#Images">Clients</a>
    </div>
        <div class="">
  <a onclick="addTHIS()" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main" style="margin-left: 250px;">
  <button class="openbtn" id="openBTN" onclick="openNav()" style="display: none;">☰  Open Sidebar</button>
    <section class="scrollspy" id="Home">
          <h1>Home</h1>
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

  <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

  <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

  <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>



  </section>

  <section class="scrollspy" id="AboutUs">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

  <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

  <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

  <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


  </section>

  <section class="scrollspy" id="Images">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

  <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

  <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

  <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


  </section>

  <section class="scrollspy" id="Contact">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

  <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. </p>

  <p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. <b>Vestibulum sapien</b>. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. <b>Sed non quam</b>. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>

  <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>


  </section>

</div>
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  document.getElementById("closeBTN").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("openBTN").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  } else {
  document.getElementById("openBTN").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("closeBTN").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
</script>
<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       var elems = $('.scrollspy');
       elems.each(function(index){
         var elemTop     = $(this).offset().top;
         var elemBottom     = elemTop + $(this).height();
         if(currentTop >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom){
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id+ '"]');
       navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
         }
       })
   });
    function addTHIS(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id+ '"]');
        navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
    }
       </script>






   
      

      
   



</body></html>
```

Comment: This concept would be much easier if you used the [intersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Here is an answer that performs a similar (but not the same) function to give you the idea of what it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/55181673#55181673

Comment: Ok I will have a look

Comment: Any help is appreciated.